# Why did a connection setting dialog box appears non stop when I try to run my program?

Tags: c#

I have a C# program and when I run the program, The connection setting dialog box keep popping up. Please see the attached pic and extend your support. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: There is no attached picture, can you please edit your post?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain your code, rather than posting an image of code

Comment: You're explicitly creating the dialog and showing it (with the `ShowDialog` call) when this code runs, it's no surprise that it pops up. What do you want to happen?

Comment: You have if showdialog ==..ok return null, this is what makes your code looping. Try to change  it to  if showdialog != ...ok

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through your code.

Comment: Please post code and not pictures of code ...

Comment: The order of operations is really weird. Shouldn't it first ask the settings, and then try to connect? Without the full code, there's really not enough information here.